# Adding a month to Ansidate

Tags: sql, vectorwise

```
select ansidate(xxx) + '3 months'  AS date1
from (
select str_to_date(varchar(max_date),'%Y%m%d') as xxx
from comp_stg_rundate
where row_key = 1
)as s
```

Max_date is saved as an interger in the comp_stg_rundate table, I want to add 3 months onto this date. The fuction DateAdd won't work as I am using VectorWise.

Comment: Don't know vectorwise, but what about adding the interval *before* converting the data to this ansidate thing: `ansidate(xxx + interval '3' month)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know VectorWise or how ansidate is stored, however, if it's stored as an integer value I assume it represents a certain amount of time, measured on a specific time unit since a starting time point.

If it's true, you can convert your 3 months to the time unit in which ansidate is being stored and add the converted value.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Vectorwise did you run this against because it works for me on VW 4.0.

However this also works.

```
timestampadd(MONTH,3,ansidate(xxx))
```

Comment: Thanks but the timestampadd function supported.